# Gmaps Plugin. Hide polygons on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Below is the code that I'm using. I'm trying to somehow make that polygon disappear when the zoom level is >= 8 but have no idea what to add. I've tried adding different variables and an event listeners but nothing has worked so far.
I've also tried an if statement and broke the map doing it.

I'm new to Javascript but understand the basics and have looked through multiple forums with no success. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

TYIA!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 55,
    lng: -94,
    zoom: 4,
  });       

var sask = 
    [[60.000000, -110.000000], 
    [60.000000, -102.000000],
    [55.812800, -101.999997], 
    [48.999473, -101.362495], 
    [48.999611, -110.004478], 
    [49.000059, -110.005026]];

var poly = map.drawPolygon({
    paths: sask,
    fillColor: '#B3B300',
    strokeColor: '#BBD8E9',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.3
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.maps.Map` objects supports `zoom_changed` event and `google.maps.Polygon` object has `setVisible` method, using which you can hide/show the poly. Check [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polygon) for more info.

To access `google.maps.Map` object in `Gmaps` in your project you have to use `map.map`. Add this to your code and it should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map.map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
     if(map.map.getZoom() >= 8){
        poly.setVisible(false);
     }else{
        poly.setVisible(true);
     }
});
```

Comment: No problem. If the answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score -1):

The `google.maps.Map` object is `map.map`.  Add a `zoom_changed` event listener to it and show/hide the map based on your criteria.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da71LzwL/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 55,
    lng: -94,
    zoom: 4,
  });

  var sask = [
    [60.000000, -110.000000],
    [60.000000, -102.000000],
    [55.812800, -101.999997],
    [48.999473, -101.362495],
    [48.999611, -110.004478],
    [49.000059, -110.005026]
  ];

  var poly = map.drawPolygon({
    paths: sask,
    fillColor: '#B3B300',
    strokeColor: '#BBD8E9',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.3
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = map.getZoom();
    if (map.getZoom() >= 8)
      poly.setMap(null);
    else
      poly.setMap(map.map);
  })
});
```

```css
body,
html,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.12/gmaps.min.js"></script>
<div id="zoom"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```